# How can I display the symbology of the child layer of a parent layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

I am working with layers in relations by a sub form (relations from 1 to n, relations established in the project properties named as "DB").
Parent layer: peoples with name (main form). Point layer (geopackage).
Child layer: the details of peoples fortune (sub-form without geometry geopackage).

How can I display the symbology of the child layer from the parent layer?

For example to display the totality of the fortune by proportional circles or an element of the fortune in particular like money cash (argent), buildings (immeubles), goods (marchandises).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To draw proportional circles, use data driven override of the symbol size and select assistant. Select a source (or use an expression to create one). Aggregate functions can help you for cummulated values like sum (total). However, the exact problem you have is not yet clear to me. Sharing a sample of your data/ your project could be helpful.

Comment: @Babel I am able to to this but my difficulty is to use the data of the child table from the parent table.

Comment: You could join the child layer to the parent layer (in layer properties) so that the attributes from the child layer are added to the parent layer.

Comment: @Babel here the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fl7Oh5cI0y7Rv9qUWNVwo46RapaShjlM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When I join the two layer, my attribute table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3nNA.png - however, there is no field to use for size - at least of the entries is a `NULL` value

Comment: @Babel very helpfull : i didnt know  I need to do an attribute joint between child and parent tables.Than you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a parent/child relationship, I suggest you should try using a [table join](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=join#joins-properties) so that the attributes from the child layer are added to the parent layer.

Right click your `parent layer / Properties / Joins`, than create a new join and add the child table, defining the unique id's of both tables that should be connected and maybe also add a prefix for the imported attributes.

*This is how it looks like with the data you provided. Attributes with a name beginning with `imp_` are imported from the other table:*

[image: screenshot]